# Remote database access is not working on cpanel VPS

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a database on one cpanel server using a php file on a different cpanel server.
No matter what I try, it is simply not working.

I have added the ip of second server (the one which is trying to connect) into the "Remote database access" cpanel setting of server1 (the server with database)

WHM also has a similar setting, "additional mysql access hosts". I added the IP there also.

My password had an "@" character, which I read will not work with grant command, so I created a new user.
Cpanel won't let me create a user without a special character in password, so I used the ">" sign instead.
Then I added this user to the desired database.

Then I ran the below grant command on server1 which has the database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'full_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password' with grant option;
```

I checked /etc/my.cnf file and it does not has a bind-address line.
I restarted the mysql service

Then when PHP file on second server tries to connect to database on server1, it still does not work.
I am not sure what the problem is. I am completely lost.

Comment: It could be a [firewall](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/general-systems-administration/how-to-configure-your-firewall-for-cpanel-services/) issue. make sure the correct port is open to access the MySQL database.

Comment: how do I check firewall etc in WHM/CPANEL? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the link I gave? You can also look this up.

Comment: And please share the exact error you received as without it, we can only guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you share your connection code and the error you received, we can give estimated answers.

1. Your server's firewall may be blocking external connections.
2. Your code may be incorrect, you should review it again.

Comment: It was the firewall. It's working now, finally! Thanks. I have selected your answer. Also, the php error log is not showing me the error code. It simply says access denied for 'user'@'ip' in php file on line 39

Comment: Access denied error does not indicate problem with firewall, but problems with mysql user name and/or password or issue with mysql permissions. This is a mysql error, not a php one.